# CMAK Error A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, yahoo-kafka-manager

I have integrated the ELK system concept in node js. So Kibana , Kafka, kafka manager, Zookeeper are installed in docker in my local system. Everything is running in the docker window perfectly. I am getting some errors so I could not create a cluster in CMAK. Please find the attachment. Could you help me?[image: Kafka Manager is loaded in browser]

[image: Docker are working Perfect]

ElasticSearch.yaml

```
version : "3.7"
services: 
elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    restart : always
    environment :
        - xpack.security.enabled=false
        - discovery.type=single-node
        - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms750m -Xmx750m
    ulimits :
        memlock: 
            soft: -1
            hard: -1
        nofile:
            soft: 65536
            hard: 65536
    cap_add:
        - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
        - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
        - "9200:9200"
kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.12.0
    restart: always
    environment:
        - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://192.168.29.138:9200
        - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=http://192.168.29.138:9200 
    ports:
        - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
        - elasticsearch  
volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:
```

Kafka.yaml

```
version : "3"
services: 
zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper
    restart : always
    container_name: zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
        - 2181:2181
    environment:
        ZOO_MY_ID: 1
kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
        - 9092:9092
    environment:
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME : 192.168.29.138
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
kafka_manager:
    image: hlebalbau/kafka-manager:stable
    container_name: kafka-manager
    restart : always
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    environment:
        ZK_HOST : "zookeeper:2181"
        APPLICATION_SECRET: "random-secret"
    command: -Dpidfile.path=/dev/null
```

Comment: 1) Please add your files as text, not images 2) In your error, `kafka-manager-system` hostname doesn't exist for the `akka://` protocol 3) Your services should be part of the same compose file since you don't have a common network 4) As part of a [mcve], it doesn't appear your error has anything to do with an ELK stack 5) `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` should refer to the contianer service name, not some IP address

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I am new to kafka-manager and ELK system. so I did not get what you said exactly. please could you tell what should i change in my code. Then I will check and let you know

Comment: ELK is not part of the issue here, so it's distracting and you should remove it from the question. Then, `ZK_HOSTS` is the correct variable name https://github.com/hleb-albau/kafka-manager-docker#how-to-use-this-image